# What's the "format" file in VisualSVN repository?

Tags: svn, visualsvn, visualsvn-server

There is a file called 'format' in the root repository folder. It contains the number 5.

Does it mean our SVN Server is running on SVN 1.5 ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it just identifies the format of the repository file system, which the svn developers might need to change every now and then.

Answer (score 0):

Number 5 indicates that your repository is created with subversion 1.7